# Supported video sizes MediaRecorder API android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to record the contents of the screen using mediarecorder and mediaprojection api. When I'm trying to change the video to HD on my device the recording fails but it works fine with 640 x 480 resolution. So my question is how could I get the supported video resolutions on a particular device?
Cheers Jon

Comment: Jake Wharton's been using `CamcorderProfile` in his Telecine app: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine/blob/master/telecine/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/telecine/RecordingSession.java

Comment: @CommonsWare `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH` doesn't return the highest supported resolution, my device supports 2k and 4k video recording, but it returns Full HD resolution

Answer (score 2):

If your only interest is in API 21+, you can use the [`getVideoCapabilities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#getVideoCapabilities()) method.

The [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) class has been around since API 8, but isn't quite as useful.

If all else fails, use trial and error, testing each desired resolution and flagging the ones that don't work.

Comment: I could do that but I want to support as wide range of android devices as I can if I'll hard-code the resolutions it won't work on all devices

Comment: I'm not sure what part of my answer sounds like hard-coding resolutions.

Comment: Okay I've used the getVideoCapabilities method but I have problems with making the recording with default screen resolution, even though the getVideoCapabilities tells me that the framerate, width and height is supported the app crashes.

Comment: @fadden Updated my question with some info about devices, it seems `MediaCodecInfo` makes sense but still 4K fails on some devices for video recording with `MediaRecorder` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846234/mediarecorder-java-io-ioexception-prepare-failed-for-4k-resolutions-on-some